# Menu list items: Full width (border-bottom)?

Tags: css, list, menu

I have a menu from a list. On small widths I want the border-bottom  to use the full width:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2 with Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3 with more Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5 with Text</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu li:not(.active) {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}
#menu li.active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
#menu li a {
    padding: .5em 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}
```

Test: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrz39p4L/)**

Comment: You can achieve best results if you use flexbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a background image, you're going to have to get creative. How about this...

```js
var li = $("#menu li");

li.click(function () {
    li.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #eee;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #fff;
}
a {
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu {
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style:inline;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    margin: 0 1em 1em;
}
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
#menu li:after {
    content: " ";
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -2px;
 right: -1000px;
 width: 1000px;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
 z-index: 1;
}
#menu li:not(.active) {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}
#menu li.active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
#menu li:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-right: -.275em;
}
#menu li a {
    padding: .5em 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2 with Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3 with more Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5 with Text</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect flow now on all widths :)

Answer (score 1):

flexbox (as mention by Luis P.A.) can help here by making the `li` fill with full width of the `ul` and wrapping as required.

Flexbox Support is IE10 and up.

```js
var li = $("#menu li");

li.click(function() {
  li.removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #fff;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  margin: 0 1em 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#menu li {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: relative;
}
#menu li:not(.active) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}
#menu li.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
#menu li:not(:last-of-type) {} #menu li a {
  padding: .5em 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2 with Text</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3 with more Text</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5 with Text</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Nicely done. If support <IE10 isn't an issue, this is the best solution. Works with flexible layout too so no problem on responsive sites.